# Which formula for kinetic energy of 1 mol of a gas is universally applicable?

Tags: kinetic-theory-of-gases

I have read 2 formulas for kinetic energy of 1 mol of gas - 3/2 RT and 1/2fRT . But if I equate them then f comes out to be 3 . But f is different of mono, di, polyatomic gases . Where am I wrong in my deduction that 3/2RT = 1/2 fRT ? Do these 2 formulas produce same result for a particular gas?

Comment: _"Acceptable"_ is not a thing that a formula may or may not be. You might want to go with _"applicable"_, but then again, it is not comparable in terms like _"more"_ or _"less"_. $3/2$ is applicable when $f=3$, as you correctly deduced; otherwise it isn't.

Comment: Ek=3/2RT is universally applicable as the translational part of kinetic energy of an ideal gas. I.e. molecular rotation and vibration is not included,

Comment: Simply put, it is used when you don't yet know about any gases other than monoatomic.

Comment: Thanks guys .. but I want to know if  can I equate these 2 equations

Comment: Yes when they are equal, and no when they aren't.

Comment: Thank you .. In what cases they are not equal?

Comment: So the formula 1/2 fRT is universally applicable but 3/2RT is only applicable for monoatomic gases ... Am I right ?

Comment: @DeboditRay Ask yourself rather, how you get $f$ for a given gas.